# asp grid view paging is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my asp gird asp grid paging is not working what is the problem is my code please help me.. problem is when i click the paging items page is not post back..

here is  my aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Font-Size = "11pt" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PagerSettings-Visible="true" PageSize="4" CssClass="footable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        Style="max-width: 500px" DataKeyNames="Id" EnableViewState="true" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Edit" ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/image/redit.png" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDescription" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("ProductImage") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ProductImage")) : string.Empty %>' alt="image" height="80" width="80" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Delete" ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/image/rdelete.png" />
        </Columns>
            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign = "Right"  />
     </asp:GridView>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/css/footable.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/js/footable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=GridView1]').footable();
        });
    </script>
```

and here is my aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    string val = (string)this.GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex]["Id"];

    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {

    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {

    }
}

public void LoadGrid()
{
    try
    {
        BusinessLogic.clsGeneral objGen = new BusinessLogic.clsGeneral();
        string strquery = "select * from Products where status = 1";
        DataTable dt = objGen.ExecuteQueryReturnDatatable(strquery);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

You need to Bind Your GridView Again in `PageIndexChanging` event

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    LoadGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add datasource agin to your paging,

Try replacing the below snippet from yours.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  BusinessLogic.clsGeneral objGen = new BusinessLogic.clsGeneral();
  string strquery = "select * from Products where status = 1";
  DataTable dt = objGen.ExecuteQueryReturnDatatable(strquery);
  GridView1.DataSource = dt;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

*some points still here to be mentioned*

Avoid inLine queries, that doesn't seems good

inspite calling data all over again to bind, you can use some other trick as well.

And in Sql ,never return *(all) , return only sets of column you need, * is not good practice.
Eg. select name,address,phone from .... instead of select *...

Comment: but what the problem in my code page is not post back when i click the item

Answer (score -1):

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery").Include(
              "~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js",
               "~/Scripts/jquery.ui.min.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/customscripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/BeatPicker.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js",
                     "~/Scripts/legacy.js",
                    "~/Scripts/custombox.js",
                    "~/Scripts/ion.rangeSlider.js",
                    "~/Scripts/ion.rangeSlider.min.js",

                     "~/Scripts/iCheck/icheck.min.js",
            // "~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker1.min.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.monthyearpicker.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.akordeon.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.autogrow-min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.corner.js",
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.